# WebApi Custom Routing in dotnet Core

Tags: .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi

In dotnet core, I'm trying to create a webapi endpoint that have a value before the controller name.
ex:

template: "api/{AccountId}/[controller]"

endpoint "api/435ABC/Reports/EndOfYear"

I've seen many examples on how to do this in MVC and in Framework 4.x, but not many with WebApi and where I set a parameter before the controller name.

Answer (score 3):

In **attribute routing** you should change your controller route to `[Route("api")]` to accept all calls from `https://example.com/api`.

**Note:** it will affect all routes inside the **Reports** controller.

```
[Route("api")]
public class ReportsController : ApiController
```

and then decorate your action with route attribute like below:

```
[Route("{id}/[controller]/[action]")]
```

this way you can call your action method with `https://example.com/api/435ABC/Reports/EndOfYear`.

In **convention-based routing** you should only add route in **UseMvc** method and remove **Route** attributes from controller and action:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"); // this line specifies default route
    routes.MapRoute(name: "Reports", template: "api/{id}/{controller=Reports}/{action=EndOfYear}"); // this line specifies your custom route
});
```

Comment: I get the following error:
InvalidOperationException: The constraint entry 'id' - 'string' on the route 'api/{id:string}/{controller=Reports}/{action=EndOfYear}' could not be resolved by the constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver'.

Comment: @Brian My bad, you don't need to include `string` in route constraints. Here is my target framework: **`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>`**, and it's working properly. [Here](https://pastebin.com/RudrY5u3) is what I did.